# When can/can't my userscript trigger a right-click (context menu) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, contextmenu, greasemonkey

I've found a lot of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579589/how-to-generate-a-right-click-event-in-all-browsers/), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914684/trigger-right-click-using-pure-javascript), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250447/trigger-right-click), purporting to show how to "simulate a right click" or "trigger the context menu", etc.  Then I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241478/how-do-i-trigger-the-browser-context-menu-on-an-element-as-if-the-user-right-c), which simply says it can't be done.  I think the first 3 questions are all triggering *custom* context menus, i.e. menus that are attached to replace the built-in one.  I'd like to just simulate a user right-click on a particular element of my choice.

I've tried all the suggestions in the first questions -- varying combinations of `createEvent("MouseEvents" / "HTMLEvents")` and `initEvent / initMouseEvent("click" / "contextmenu")`, jQuery's [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), etc.  Nothing makes the default context menu appear.

Is it truly impossible?  Does the fact that I'm running "privileged" from a userscript (in Greasemonkey) make any difference?  Could I do it from a full-weight Firefox extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the first three answers, that you linked, are for custom menus/controls.

The fourth answer is correct; you can't activate the browser's context menu(s) -- for the same reasons you can't activate the browser's normal menus... It would be a huge security hole that bad guys would exploit.

Likewise Greasemonkey scripts can't do this either.  Greasemonkey scripts have *some* elevated privileges (only when running in sandboxed mode, as of GM 1.0), but the developers of Greasemonkey have not chosen to make context-menus available. (Nor have I heard of a pressing need for such a feature.)

I'm pretty sure that a full-fledged add-on, *could* activate context menus (or menu items), but I've never tried it and can't provide code, at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's as close to a "never nowhere no-how" as I'm going to get.  Oh well!

Comment: You're welcome, and sorry.  I'm browsing through [a search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[firefox-addon]%20%22context%20menu%22) and I don't see (yet) that someone's even done this with an add-on/extension. (Doesn't mean it's not possible for an add-on, even if no one's asked about it on SO yet.)