# How can I make a left-click behave as a right-click?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I could make a left-click behave as a right-click in javascript. I would like that, by doing a left click, the context menu appears.

Regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250447/trigger-right-click

Comment: Please post your code...? and also please refer http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#example-5

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but I forgot to say I am not using jquery

Comment: You did not have to say you did not use jQuery, people need to read the tags or ask if in doubt

Comment: I hoped this would work but it didn't: `link.onclick=function() { this.oncontextmenu(); return false }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a click-event listener to the document
2. save what element was the lowest in the dom-tree that got clicked
3. fire an event 'rightclick' (or whatever its called) to that element with the same x and y coords as you have received from the click event.

The event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

This gives you already a lot of information. You'll get the x/y coords of your mouseclick and more important, you get the element that received the click: [e.originalTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485453/best-way-to-get-the-original-target) (note that events differ from browser to browser).

save the element:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var originalElement = e.srcElement || e.originalTarget;
});
```

and fire a right-click on that element:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var originalElement = e.srcElement || e.originalTarget;
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        ev.initEvent('contextmenu', true, false);
        originalElement .dispatchEvent(ev);
    } else { // Internet Explorer
        originalElement .fireEvent('oncontextmenu');
    }
});
```

## edit:

it does not seem to work yet, so consider using this method for firing the right-click in pure js: [How to generate a right-click event in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579589/how-to-generate-a-right-click-event-in-all-browsers/1580660#1580660)

Comment: You mean something like : document.addEventListener("click", function(e){e.target.oncontextmenu = function(){} }, false); ?

Comment: It doesn't work :P What I would need is to make the context menu appear by left clicking on an element :)

Comment: The link seems to be like you said, it doesn't work. I am keeping searching the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $(document).contextmenu(function (event) {
        $(event.target).click();
        event.preventDefault();
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am not using jquery

Comment: This is the other way around. Right click triggering left click